# How to join the results of a subquery to a table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, subquery, database-table

hello i'm newbie in sql (postgresql)
i have 2 tables **as result** of 2 differen selects

```
       all calls                    our customer contacts
   number contact_id      and     contact_id    name
    3213      12                        12     jonh
    3213      34                        16     michael
    3213      43                        65     hewlet
    5432      16                        32     steward
    5432      51
    6543      65
    2322      54
    2322      32
```

1 number can belong to different contacts... (contacts belong to different customers) i need to select 
distinct numbers from 1st result table. and names of this contacts from 2nd table..

and how i must unite my 2 selects

thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will not be able to use the `distinct` keyword, as you actually want to select also the `contact_id` from the `all_calls` table. Instead, you will need to use one of the aggregate functions to select a single `contact_id` for each distinct phone number.

In this example I use the `min()` function, which will give me the contact with the numerically lowest `contact_id` for each phone number:

```
select tmp.number, contacts.name
from (
  select number, min(contact_id) as min_id
  from all_calls
  group by number
) as tmp
join contacts on tmp.min_id = contacts.contact_id
```

Comment: thanks. but why  min() ?. and "our customer contacts" its result of 
select id from contacts where customer_id = '51'

Comment: As I understand your question, you just want *one* name pr. called phone number. If two contacts have been called on the same number, a `min()` or `max()` on the `contact_id` can be used to select just *one* value. Assuming that `contact_id` does not hold any business value, both functions are in practice "random".

Comment: Wouldn't you be able to simply append `where customer_id = 51` to the end of the query? Of course, this assumes that no two contacts from *different* companies share the same phone number.